# Backbone.js: Change datetime field from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

When I print the created_at field of a model using Backbone.js( `<i> {{created_at}} </i>`
 ), I'm getting: `2011-08-07T12:03:00Z`.

I'm trying to change the date to a readable format for hours and I'm not being able to.

I want the T and Z to be removed before printing.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the variable in your template context, or add a new one. I would add a new one.

If this is in your render function, it may be changed to something like this:

```
render: function() {
  var context = this.model.toJSON();
  context['created_at_formatted'] = this.formatDate(context['created_at']);
  var html = this.template.to_html(context);
  $(this.el).html(html);
}
```

With a function added to the view like this:

```
formatDate: function(d) {
  var pad = function (n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
  };

  // in case the date is a string; you can remove this if you know it will be a date
  if (typeof date === 'string') {
    d = new Date(d);
  }

  return [
    d.getUTCFullYear(), '-',
    pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1), '-',
    pad(d.getUTCDate()), ' ',
    pad(d.getUTCHours()), ':',
    pad(d.getUTCMinutes()), ':',
    pad(d.getUTCSeconds())
  ].join("");
}
```

Then the template would be like this:

```
<i> {{created_at_formatted}} </i>
```

To simplify the date formatting function, you could also use a date formatting library like [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/). You could also move the date formatting to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Readable? Why not jQuery timeago?
[jQuery timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

In your Backbone model,

```
toTemplateData: -> 
  _.extend
    created_duration: do => $.timeago @get("created_at") if @get("created_at")
```

In your Backbone view,

```
render: ->
  @$el.html(@template(@model.toTemplateData() ))
```

In your template,

```
<time title="{{created_duration}}"></time>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strftime on your created_at

```
<i> {{created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}} </i>
```

Comment: It does not work. It doesn't load any data when I add .strftime.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer is correct but the formatting of the date should really be in a model somewhere as it is business logic.

My variation of that would be:

```
render: function() {
  var context = this.model.format().toJSON();
  var html = this.template.to_html(context);
  $(this.el).html(html);
}
```

And in your model, something like:

```
format() {
  this.set('created_at_formatted', formatDate(this.get('created_at')));
  return this;
}

formatDate: function(d) {
  // format date stuff (See Ben`s answer)
  return d;
}
```

And your template would render:

```
<i> {{created_at}} </i>
```

This removes some redundancy, promotes reuse and it is easier to read. Perhaps my answer needs a little work but hopefully you get the general idea.

Comment: Formatting of a date isn't really business logic - it's presentation and should be rendered in the view.